# Creating Pointcut annotation in Spring aspectj in Java

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am using `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut`. I have an interface com.home.learn.Try.

- I want a pointcut annotation created to watch all methods of that class that implemets the interface (com.home.learn.Try)

I used @Pointcut("execution(com.home.learn.Try.*(..))") but i got the error

```
Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 34
execution(com.home.learn.Try.*(..))
```

- I want a pointcut to watch(specific method) com.home.learn.Try.print(java.lang.String) method

Also I am curious about how to create pointcut annotation to watch all methods of a concrete class which extends an abstract class.

Thanks

Comment: Write some code. If it doesn't work, post it here, along with the error messages. Don't ask for free code without putting in some effort of your own.

Comment: Also: are you using @AspectJ-style Spring AOP or real aspectj (with aspectj compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `execution(* com.home.learn.Try.*(..))`.

You can find a cheat sheet [here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/pointcut/).

Comment: execution(* com.home.learn.Try.print(String)), regarding the second question i don't understand, if it's one class then it doesn't matter if it's extending anything. If you want _all_ subclasses of a given class, use .AbstractClassName+.*(..). 
Also I have a suggestion, accept more questions thus increase your chances of getting an answer. (hinthint)

Comment: Can you please give me an example reg using with abstract classes?

Comment: What do you mean exactly about abstract classes? Can you post a new question and explain there?